# Can't install filmic blender on Gentoo

Tags: filmic-blender

I put the filmic blender files in `/usr/share/blender/2.79/datafiles/colormanagement` as normal and the default `sRGB` values still show.

Comment: How did you install blender? Where is the blender executable file located? Do you have the right permissions to copy to the  colormanagement folder? Did you rename the filmic blender folder as colormanagement?

Comment: @cegaton I installed the normal way on gentoo of `emerge -aq blender` yes I renamed the files. All the folders and files are in the same spot as ubuntu. I can use filmic on the tar.gz version of blender but I have special CFLAGS I wanna use